# Use abstract base class to force implementation of class property?

Tags: python, abstract-class

I would like to use an abstract base class to force implementation of a *class* attribute in a concrete class. I know how to force implementation of a generic attribute using `@abc.abstractproperty`. There are lots of SO answers about how to do that - I've read about 10 of them :) But I would like to ensure that the concrete class must define the abstract attribute as a class attribute and NOT as an instance attribute. Anyone know how to do this?

EDITED to address question:

I have users who will define concrete classes from the ABC. Certain abstract properties need to be "concretized" as class attributes. The checking needs to happen the first time they instantiate the concrete class - not sooner. Ideally, if they mistakenly define an abstract property as an instance attribute, a TypeError will be raised that flags their mistake.

**The point is that the value of the class attribute should be the same for all instances of the concrete class.**

I think I am missing some knowledge about Python internals that would help me address this question properly...

```
import abc

class MyABC(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta       
    @abc.abstractproperty
    def foo():
        return 'we never run this line'

# I want to enforce this kind of subclassing
class GoodConcrete(MyABC):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        return 1 # value is the same for all class instances

# I want to forbid this kind of subclassing
class BadConcrete(MyABC):   
    def foo(self, val):
        self.foo = val
```

Comment: I think you need to give a little more description about how this is supposed to work.  Normally, abc validation happens when you try to instantiate a class.  If you're trying to assert that there is a property on the _class_, then (in principle), instantiation hasn't necessarily happened yet.  _when_ do you want this to be checked?  Also, be careful how you answer this question -- If you want it to be checked at class creation time, that might prevent you from making abstract subclasses of the abstract base class...

Comment: Jeez. This is a perfectly reasonable question and I am working hard to pose it well. Why the downvote?

Comment: Could you add one example of "concrete classes" that correctly implement your expected behaviour and one (or more) that don't? The clarification actually helps a bit but it's still confusing, at least to me. (As a side note: I didn't downvote but if you could give some examples of how the expected behaviour should be then I'll certainly upvote the question.)

Comment: Thanks @MSeifert, working on that now. I didn't think it would be such a confusing question :(

Comment: When you say that `BadConcrete` should be forbidden is it because it doesn't implement `foo` as `classmethod` or because it tries to set `self.foo`?

Comment: `foo` needs to be the same for all class instances. The user should not be able to set it by instance.

Comment: Do you need it to fail when they do `instance = BadConcrete()` or when they do `instance.foo(value)` ? because the latter is easier.

Comment: @salparadise Upon class instantiation, so the former.

Comment: Well, I've run the SO gauntlet and there's no answer. Just people complaining about how I didn't pose the question perfectly. :(